# How to show hourly (1-24) data from SQL DB on the Infopath 2010 form based on an item selected by the user

Tags: infopath, infopath2010, infopath-forms-services

I store all the hourly & monthly data for a product on our SQL Table, could you through me your suggestion on how to show the all 24 hours data on the to the table/repeating table. I am able to populate all other data on to the form for the product that the user selects. But I am unable to show all the 24hours on the table. I tried repeating table as well as general table to pull the data from the SQL DB.

Does any of you come across the task like the above please guide me with your valuable comments. Thanks.

Comment: can you please clarify your question? at the moment it is really unclear what you are asking. thanks!

Comment: My sincere apologies for not putting in clearly. Here is what i am looking for,  I have SQL Table that stores all the hourly values (1-24) of a customer. I need to bring these data on to Infopath 2010 form. Whenever an end user selects a customer the details should populate on the form (fetched from SQL DB). I am able to bring all the other details on the form except the hourly values. I dont know to loop the 24 hr data on the infopath table for the selected customer.

Comment: Something similar to filtering table/repeating table based on customer selection. But, dont know how to implement it on Infopath 2010